# phalcon - before executing view event?

Tags: php, phalcon

I want to execute:

> $this->view->setVar("menus",$menus);

before the view gets executed.

$menus is an array that can be added by different controllers.

Finally before executing the view i want to put the menus var in the view.

Answer (score 2):

Pick one of the [Dispatcher's Events](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/dispatching.html#dispatch-loop-events) that best suits your needs, then add a method in your controller with same name of the picked event. You can implement this method on your controller base class. For example, adding the `$menus` in all views for the `indexAction`:

```
class MenuControllerBase extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
  public function beforeExecuteRoute($dispatcher)
  {
    if($dispatcher->getActionName() == 'index') {
      if(isset($this->menus)) {
        $this->view->menus = $this->menus;
      }
    }
  }
}
```